# Error:Some file crunching failed, see logs for details afer update gradle

Tags: android

Afer update gradle version to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'` I got this error.

```
Error:Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

AAPT err(Facade for 596378712): \\?\C:\Users\Я\.android\build-cache\2fe51ff37440fab8f5f875609a799aebf31c9e02\output\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 596378712): \\?\C:\Users\Я\.android\build-cache\2fe51ff37440fab8f5f875609a799aebf31c9e02\output\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 596378712): \\?\C:\Users\Я\.android\build-cache\2fe51ff37440fab8f5f875609a799aebf31c9e02\output\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_015.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
```

I'm not using 9.png files. **How can I fix it?**

Comment: I have the same problem after upgrade to Studio 2.3 and build tools 2.25. Have you resolve it?

Comment: please vote for https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=236304

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have exactly same problem in **Android Studio 2.3**.
I wasted 2 days to solve this problem.

Your problem is

```
AAPT err(Facade for 596378712): \\?\C:\Users\Я\.android\build- .....
```

Folder name of your `account(reverse R?)` is not `ascii` folder name, so `build-cache` cannot recognize your folder.

**To Solve:**

1. Change folder name : it's impossible in windows 10.
2. not use build cache: Leos Literak's answer. not good solution.
3. Best solution: change build-cache path.
   refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache.html

**For Ex:**

```
in gradle.properties
android.buildCacheDir=D:/android-studio/build-cache
```

You can build your app cleanly.
Thanks.

Comment: Actually I have proposed both solutions: disable build cache / change cache location. I feel like you copied my investigation.

Comment: i am using windows 10 i did your method but still showing same error

Comment: Thx,the same problem,but just occurring in my CI server,I use this property disable gradle cache .
```
./gradlew assembleDebug -Pandroid.enableBuildCache=false
```

Answer (score 6):

I have upgraded to Studio 2.3 as well and this error suddenly occured.

```
AAPT: \\?\C:\Users\Leoš\.android\build-cache\ce4c6faf7b6acf7c9a9f7875a69dc5776c2cfd5b\output\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\msbp_math_compass.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
```

I realized one similarity in your and my logs: non-ASCII characters in user name. Then I found that it is a [build cache](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/build-cache) directory. And there was info how to turn it on. So I tried to turn it off with:

gradle.properties

```
android.enableBuildCache=false
```

And it works! I can compile my project again. I submitted [issue 236304](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=236304) to Google.

Another option is to change build cache location:

```
android.enableBuildCache=true
android.buildCacheDir c:\\Dev\\Android\\cache\\
```

Answer (score 2):

I started getting this error too with Android Studio 2.3 on Mac. Neither disabling the buildCache nor changing the location of the buildCache resolved the problem.

**Renaming** all of my **9-patch** drawables from 'xyz.9.png' to 'xyz.png' - removing the '.9' in the filename - **fixed** the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check your png files, in my case that was the problem (One picture was a JPEG file with .png at is end)
Remove it/them and remplace it/them by "real" png files and it may works

Comment: I seem to have some corrupted images files causing this error.  Sometimes it is the simple things.

Answer (score 1):

The path of the file might be too long for the compiler to build with it. Try moving your project to another location to reduce the length of the destination.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same situation as @wooldridgetm.

Later I found that if my 9-patch file has marked stretch area for both left and top side, not only one side, then the problem is solved.

I don't know if it is allowed to have only one side before. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to **1 corrupted image file in drawable**.
I changed it and the problem was solved very quickly.
The answer is very simple, but the error message is rather ambiguous.
I changed the gradle and android studio, but the solution was very simple than what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was some corrupted PNG file in resources too.
Try going through all of your images and see if you are able to view them in some external preview program.